# How do I remove all page formatting from NSString

Tags: nsstring, nsstringencoding

I have an NSMutableString* (theBigString) that contains text loaded from an online file.  I am writing theBigString to a local file on the iPad and then emailing it as an attachment.

```
[theBigString appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Despite my best efforts using the following lines of code, when I open the email attachment there still exists multiple lines of text instead of one long line of text which is what I expected (and need for my app to work).

```
[theBigString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s+" withString:@" "];
[theBigString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
[theBigString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "];
[theBigString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@" "];
```

If I open the text file and view the formatting it still shows a couple of new paragraph symbols.

Is there another newline type character besides "\n" or "\r" that I am not stripping with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSCharacterSet defines [NSCharacterSet newLineCharacterSet] as (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/newlineCharacterSet)

If you don't care too much about efficiency, you could also just separate the string into an array at the newline character locations and combine it again with empty strings.

```
NSArray* stringComponents = [theBigString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
theBigString = [stringComponents componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: This worked like a champ!  I have no idea why what I was doing didn't.  As an aside I used @" " in componentsJoinedByString to put the spaces back.